# Supremum notation

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I hope I will be forgiven for having such a basic question. I am trying to understand Definition 1.21 of [Meng.](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Categories_of_Convex_Sets_and_of_Metric.html?id=QPT8twAACAAJ&redir_esc=y) I paste the definition here:

[image]

I assume this can be written with more traditional notation as $-\text{log } \text{sup }S$ for some subset $S.$ But what should $S$ be ?

Comment: Alternatively consider the set$$\{(t,c)\in[0,1]\times C:a=tb+(1-t)c\}$$and consider the supremum of the projection of this set onto the first coordinate.

Comment: @Filippo this coincides with my answer.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, I just thought that the expression$$\sup_{(c,t):a=tb+(1-t)c}t$$may be considered a bit **visually** "closer" (ha!) to Meng's expression :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meng's definition is not rigorously formulated because of his $\exists$  before $t$. My guess is that he meant $$-\log\sup\{t\in[0,1]\mid\exists c\in C,\;a=tb+(1-t)c\}.$$

Comment: That was also my guess